# Unable to add Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, dashboard, wordpress-plugin-creation

Unable to add wp plugin. It shows an error on page.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGYQE.png)

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the FTP permissions.
Check if the web user has sudo permision to install plugin inside wp-content/plugin folder.
Else the next method is download plugin from wordpress repository and unzip. Then upload inside wp-content/plugin
then go to plugins section on wp backend and click activate